# javaのScannerクラスについて

Tags: java

以下のソースコードを実行し,漢字の入力を行ったところ,
`System.out.print(i);` で出力がされません.

```java
package app;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in,"utf-8");
        String i = scan.next();
        System.out.print(i);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

【実行環境】
・jdk-13.0.1
・VScode
(足りないものがあれば追記します)

ご教授をお願いいたします.

【追記】
日本語入力に対応していないようです.また,デバッグモードで実行したところ,
scan.next();を行った際に値の代入が"  "となってしまい,代入できていないように思えます.
英語入力では出力が得られていることから,日本語の入力に問題があるのではないかと考えています.

Comment: `System.out.print()`を使うなら、`System.out.flush()`が必要では？ [標準入出力](https://www.cis.twcu.ac.jp/~asakawa/java_intro/io.html) あとは utf-8 を使うなら出力側も encoding 指定が関係するとか？ [System.out.printlnで文字コードを変更or指定する](https://qiita.com/gw_cule/items/470128e82dc7b845959b)

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます.
追記にも記載しましたが,"日本語が代入出来ていない"ので問題は,出力ではないように思えます.

Comment: Windows 上でお使いでしたら文字コードの問題かもしれません。`new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8");` の `"utf-8"` を `"ms932"` に変更するとどうなるでしょうか。

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます.
Windows上で動かしている為,変更を加えて実行しましたが,以前と同様の結果が得られます.

Comment: [コンソール入力](http://www.kusa.ac.jp/~kajiura/java/console/console3.htm) のように、Scanner を通さない入力はどうなのか？ から調べてみては？

Comment: vscodeの日本語入力の問題のようです。vscodeの外の`cmd`で実行は動作すると思います。

Comment: この記事 [VScodeのデバッグ結果の日本語文字化け改善方法について](https://teratail.com/questions/180547) のような状況かも？

Comment: System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));　で文字コードを確認して、この文字コードを利用すれば行けると思います。

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます.

Comment: 問題はVScodeにありそうでした.javacを使ってソースをshift-jisに変え,scannerの"UTF-8"を削除したところ動きました.